# Can't install IPy library

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I tried installing the ipy library on pip3 it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement IPy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for IPy
```

I tried using pip instead of but it just says requirement already satisfied yet every script I have with the import wont work and for some reason the pip3 command worked in pycharm but didnt work in my terminal.
python 3.8 and ubuntu linux

Comment: Try this:
pip install --upgrade pip It should update pip

Comment: If you are using python 3.8, then you might have a problem: "*IPy 1.01 works on Python version 2.6 - 3.7.*" (https://github.com/autocracy/python-ipy#compatibility-and-links)

Comment: "*I tried installing the ipy library on pip3*" Please [edit] to show the exact command/s you used on the command line, and it would help to show the outputs of `python -V`, `pip -V`, and `pip3 -V`.

Comment: gino thanks for your feed back ill be more descriptive in my next question and your original theory is correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason it worked in pycharm is probably because it uses a different python and pip version. You should keep this in mind whenever you use an IDE with a lot of features like Jetbrains's IDEs and visual studio. Check the version of python that pycharm uses. This is important because like what Gino mentioned in the comments, IPy supports python 2.6 to 3.7. I recommend you use one of those versions instead.